# After git pull on server, permissions get changed

Tags: php, linux, windows, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have Linux as production server and I develop my application on windows. The thing is I want my folders to be 755 permissions on production and 644 for files. I use

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

these commands. It works well. Now let's imagine, I uploaded updated version of my app to GitHub and I pulled it on server.

What happens is after git pull, permissions or owners for folders and files get changed. So app stops working and i have to run those 2 commands to make it work again. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Get changed to WHAT?

Comment: could you add you git log ?

Comment: so owner was dexter and after pulling, some of the files'owners became root